# node.js reading two files simultaneously

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a beginner Node.js user, and I can't seem to comprehend the file reading capabilities of this framework. What I'm trying to do is the following>

I have two files, namely file1 and file2. I want to read file1 line by line and when line satisfies specific requirement (eg. when splitted,  part [2] equals to term TERM) I want to start reading file2 and do come comparisons of those lines. What I currently have:

```
 var readPDB = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(PDBname),
    output: process.stdout,
     terminal: false
 });

 var count1 = 0;


 readPDB.on('line', function (line){

    //console.log(line);
    count1++;
    console.log(count1);

});
```

If I manage to get this count thing working, I can translate that to my problem.

Comment: Why not read in the first, then the second, and go through them simultaneously?

Comment: Also tried that but the count1++ doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Wait, why do you use readline instead of the file system https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-read-files-in-nodejs/

Comment: I have to deal with relatively large files.

Comment: What is output/error after running given code?

Comment: You need to read them in completely either way.

Comment: @Bálint No he doesn't.

Comment: The count1 remains 0 after iteration @Himani

Comment: @MadaraUchiha He reads the first file, until he finds something in it, then starts reading in the second one and makes comparisons on the following lines

Comment: Tried running your code, count1 increments as lines are read. But a nth line from file A can be read before n-1th line of file B is read. Are you saving lines in an array for comparison?

Comment: @Bálint While that's true, he doesn't need to hold both files completely in memory, he can read them line by line, and only hold a relatively small buffer in memory at each point in time.

Comment: @MadaraUchila Reading lines 1 by 1 would make the GC work pretty much constantly.